# Change button color back to original value

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a version of the game [Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28game%29) in matlab and I want to make the button to return to it's original color after pushing it, however the button stays with the new color. The code I'm using is:

```
clc, clf, clear
h1=figure(1);
button1=uicontrol(h1, 'Style','Pushbutton', 'Units','Normalized','Position',...
[0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2],'Backgroundcolor', [1 0 0],...
'Callback',['value1=get(button1,''Value''); if value1==1',...
'set(button1,''Backgroundcolor'',[0 1 0]); else ,',...
'set(button1, ''BackgroundColor'',''r''), end,value2=get(button1,''Value'')']);
```

If you run it you can notice the color stays green, what can I do to return it to red automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that pressing the button only checks the `Value` property of `button1`, but does not change it for future presses. Therefore, the `Value` of `button1` is always evaluated to be the 0 and as a result the button never changes colors.

The following working code seems to do what you want:

```
clc, clf, clear
h1 = figure(1);
button1_state = 1;
button1_callback = ...
   ['if (button1_state == 1), set(button1, ''Backgroundcolor'', ''g''),' ...
    'else set(button1, ''BackgroundColor'', ''r''), end, ' ...
    'button1_state = ~button1_state;'];
button1 = uicontrol(h1, 'Style', 'Pushbutton', 'Units', 'Normalized', ...
   'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2], 'Backgroundcolor', 'r', ...
   'Callback', button1_callback);
```

What I did here is create a variable `button1_state` which holds the current "state" of `button1` (1 for red and 0 for green). In the callback operation I change the button's background color depending on the current state, and then flip the state.

Hope it helps!

P.S
Notice that I put the callback operation separately in the string `button1_callback` for readbility reasons. It would actually unfold into this:

```
if (button1_state == 1)
   set(button1, 'Backgroundcolor', 'g')
else
   set(button1, 'BackgroundColor', 'r')
end
button1_state = ~button1_state;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your code I'm thinking I could add some WindowButtonDownFcn and WindowButtonUpFcn so when I release the button it automatically changes the color without pushing it again.